# Remove last 5 elements of a map

Tags: c++

I want to remove last 5 elements from a std::map.

One way is:

```
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    map<string, LocationStruct>::iterator it = myLocations.end();
    it--; 
    myLocations.erase(it);
  }
```

Is there a good way to do that without looping?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can use the std::prev function to do navigation for you:

```
m.erase(prev(m.end(), 5), m.end());
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks, I keep mixing up next and advance.

Answer (score 3):

a compilable demo of one way to do it. Note that because map iterators are not random access iterators, there's likely to be a loop involved under the covers during the call to `std::prev()` anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

std::map<int, std::string> m = {
    { 0, "zero"s },
    { 1, "one"s },
    { 2, "two"s },
    { 3, "three"s },
    { 4, "four"s },
    { 5, "five"s }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    for (const auto& entry : m) {
        std::cout << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << std::endl;
    }

    // erase operation here
    m.erase(std::prev(m.end(), 5), m.end());

    std::cout << "\nafter erase \n\n";
    for (const auto& entry : m) {
        std::cout << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
0, zero
1, one
2, two
3, three
4, four
5, five

after erase 

0, zero
```

Answer (score 1):

Use range erase

```
auto i = m.begin();
std::advance(i, (m.size() - 5) );
m.erase( i, m.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, std::map has normal access iterator, so you have to traverse to last element every time to erase it from memory.